# concatenate two fields in Extjs store

Tags: gridview, extjs, store

Hi i'm trying to insert a new row in a grid, but one column of it is in fact a concatenation of two values, I'd like to do something like this :

```
    var scopename = newScopeRef.down('textfield[id=scope_name]').getValue();
    var prodname = newScopeRef.down('combobox[id=prd]').getRawValue();
    var relname = newScopeRef.down('combobox[id=p_rls]').getRawValue();


 var editscopegrid = newScopeRef.down('gridpanel[id=editedscope_grid]'); //my grid
    editscopegrid.getView().getStore().removeAll();
    editscopegrid.getView().getStore().add({
                       name_scope : scopename,
                       prodrel : concat(prodrel + ',' prodname + ' ' + relname)});  
    editscopegrid.getView().refresh();
```

As you can see I'd like to concatenante the existing value of the column `prodrel` of the grid with the values of the comboboxes `prodname` and `relname`, separated by a space.

I'm using Extjs 4.x with the MVC architecture, above is the handler of the click event of a button "update" on my panel.

How can I do this please?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something in the question, but you don't need a function to concatenate a string in Javascript, you're using `concat`. Just use the `+` operator. Unless I am missing what this Q is about that is the only problem with the code above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an explicit model definition you can add a `prodrel` field with a `convert` function and do the concatenation there.

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model', 
    fields : [
        'name_scope',
        'prodname',
        'relname',
        {
            name    : 'prodrel', 
            convert : function (v, rec) {
               return rec.get('prodname') + ' ' + rec.get('relname');
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you can add an instance to your store like so...

```
editscopegrid.getView().getStore().add({
                       name_scope : scopename,
                       prodname   : prodname,
                       relname    : relname});
```